# Perform HTTP get operation in SSIS to fetch information from an API

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, ssis

I'm working on an SSIS package to get some information from an API. Is there any component or an extension that I can use in SSIS to perform HTTP Request or Response operation. My **[API is in JSON format](https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/Monish/Disenrollment/1.0.0/inventory?searchString=7S6012-000001)**. It has two fields ID and date. I'm trying to get the 'date' field by providing the ID.

I'm new to c# and SSIS. Please let me know if I should I try with the script component or is there any alternative extension in SSIS to do this.

Using the script component in SSIS here is what I have tried.

Here is what I've tried after referring [this](http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-json-feed-as-data-source-in-ssis.html) article.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    string serviceDate = Variables.TaskID;
    string wUrl = "https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/Monish/Disenrollment/1.0.0/inventory?searchString=" + serviceDate;

    try
    {
        WorkGroupMetric[] outPutMetrics = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl);

        foreach( var metric in outPutMetrics)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.DisenrollmentDate = metric.CN;


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FailComponent(e.ToString());
    }

}

private WorkGroupMetric[] GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
    HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
    WorkGroupMetric[] jsonResponse = null;

    try
    {
        //Test the connection
        if(httpWResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();
            string jsonString = null;

            //Set jsonString
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\\", "");
                reader.Close();
            }

            //Desearialize our JSON
            JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            jsonResponse = sr.Deserialize<WorkGroupMetric[]>(jsonString.Trim('"'));

        }
        //Output connection error message
        else
        {
            FailComponent(httpWResp.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FailComponent(e.ToString());
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The web service task only supports http requests, the URL in the code you posted uses https. There is one another option besides the script task that I have found to be much easier to implement (in most cases), using an 'execute process' task to start powershell and subsequently execute a script to download the data. Have you tried the code you posted yet? Does that service have a 'type' parameter? If so, it would likely be easier to work with xml results.